# The $\alpha$ estimation for the model $x_i = \xi_i \cdot \alpha$

Tags: optimization, random-variables, regression, estimation, least-squares

We have $n$ sensors $X_i$ which estimate the scalar value $\alpha$ with different relative accuracies $\delta_i \ll 1$:
$$
x_i = X_i(\alpha) = \xi_i \cdot \alpha, \ \ \ \xi_i \sim N(1, \delta_i)
$$

How to find the best estimate of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to rewrite it in more standard form. Let's take noise $\epsilon_i=(\zeta_i-1)/\delta_i$ as a function of $x_i,\alpha,\delta_i$:
$$
\epsilon_i=(x_i/\alpha-1)/\delta_i
$$
Clearly $\epsilon_i=N(0,1)$.
Now you can run maximum likelihood or (that the same here least square) principle.
$$
\min_\alpha F(\alpha),~ where~ F(\alpha)=\sum_i \epsilon_i^2
$$
It is simpler with respect to $a=1/\alpha$.
$$
F(a)=\sum_i (x_i a-1)^2/\delta_i^2
$$
Analytically :
$$
F^\prime_a=\sum_i 2(x_ia-1)/\delta_i^2x_i=0
$$
So 
$$
a=\frac{\sum_i x_i/\delta_i^2}{\sum_i x_i^2/\delta_i^2}
$$
and finally 
$$
\alpha=1/a=\frac{\sum_i x_i^2/\delta^2_i}{\sum_i x_i/\delta_i^2}
$$

### UPDATE VARIANT 2

Due to very intensive discussion about my solution I decided to update and may be fix it.
So let's again rewrite the model in more standard form:
$$
x_i=\alpha+\delta_i \alpha\epsilon_i, ~ where ~\epsilon_i \in N(0,1)
$$
Let's write a -log-likelihood function  in terms of $x_i,\delta_i,a$
$$
L(x,\alpha,\delta)=-0.5\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i-\alpha)^2}{\delta_i^2 \alpha^2}-0.5 \sum_{i=1}^n \log(\alpha \delta_i)
$$
The main difference here with the initial approach is $\log(\alpha)$. The difference that  in my transformation since I deformed original $x_i$ by unknown $\alpha$ which deforms maximum likelihood and we lose this $\log$.
I am not sure which approach is more correct yet but this will give us a different result. Indeed:
Now maximizing $L$ with respect to $\alpha$ $(a=1/\alpha)$ leads to the following quadratic equation:
$$
2\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2 a^2 -x_i a}{\delta_i^2}-n=0
$$ 
Lets' denote
$$
\bar x=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{n\delta_i^2}\\
\bar {x^2}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{n\delta_i^2}
$$

So 
$$
2 \bar {x^2} a^2-2\bar x a -1=0;
$$
The equation has two roorts  but the root corresponding to the maximum is:
$$
a=  \frac{\bar x+\sqrt{(\bar x)^2+2\bar {x^2}}}{2\bar{x^2}}
$$
and finally 
$$
\alpha=1/a=\frac{2\bar{x^2}}{\bar x+\sqrt{(\bar x)^2+2\bar {x^2}}}
$$
The result seems to be even more complicating and less obvious than the original which also makes sense. The analysis of bias.mean and variance will follow.

### UPDATE VARIANT 3

Analysing the problem I got to the conclusion that the error in the measurements cannot depend on estimated $\alpha$. Instead it depends on "true $\alpha$". 
This leads to the simpler equation
$$
x_i=\alpha+\delta_i\alpha^*\epsilon_i
$$
Where $\alpha^*$ is the true $\alpha$. But then the solution becomes very simple and natural.
We have to minimize
$$
\sum_i (x_i-\alpha)^2/\delta_i^2
$$ that leads to the immediate nice solution pointed out by Did
$$
\alpha=\frac{\sum_i x_i /\delta^2_i}{\sum_i 1/\delta_i^2}
$$

### Means and Variances of the estimators

Since $x_i=N(\alpha,\alpha\delta_i)$, $E(x_i)=\alpha^*,E(x_i^2)=\alpha^2(1+\delta_i^2)$. Higher monents become more complicating and the ratio of final means and variances will be disaster.
I only can say that they will be biased even asymptotically.The variance ot the variant 1 and 2 will converge to zero as $1/n$ just because variance $1/n nominator$ and variance of $1/n denominator$ will converge to zero. Thus variance of the ratio will converge to zero too.

However for variant 3 everything is easy and straightforward. 
$$
E(x_i)=\alpha^*, Var(x_i)={\alpha^*}^2*\delta_i^2
$$

$$
E(\alpha)=\alpha^*\frac{\sum_i 1/\delta_i^2}{\sum_i 1/\delta_i^2}=\alpha^*
$$
Now variance of sum equal sum of variances, so 
$$
Var(\alpha)={\alpha^*}^2\frac{\sum_i 1/\delta_i^2}{(\sum_i 1/\delta_i^2)^2}=\frac{{\alpha^*}^2}{\sum_i 1/\delta_i^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks, but why are you use $\sum_i \epsilon_i^2$ as the goal function? We already know the distribution of $\epsilon_i$. We shouldn't to minimize the sample covariance of $\epsilon_i$ because it is already known. Moreover, in your case the sample mean of $\epsilon_i$ will sufficiently far from zero.

Comment: I just transformed the problem to the standard form. What do u mean we already know the distribution? Of course we know it follows from initial setting. When we want to estimate $y_i=\alpha x_i+\epsilon_i$ we are doing the same thing minimizing sum of squares of $\epsilon_i$ assuming them I.i.d. $N(0,1)$. $\epsilon_i$ is not observable.

Comment: The Gauss–Markov theorem for the least squares estimator (LSE) assume that residuals are i.i.d. and we don't know the true form of its distribution. In that case will get the best linear unbiased estimator for a linear regression model which gives us the lowest variance of the estimate. In our case a distribution of residuals is well known. We can't use LSE because we don't need to minimize the variance of residuals.

Comment: I think that a good estimation of $\alpha$ shoud make PDF of $\epsilon_i$ most similar to $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Do u want to say that your $\zeta_i$are not independent?  Then u should say something about this.  Because if they are independent I have to say that u don't understand what gauss markov theorem says.  It does not matter we know or don'

Comment: or don't the distribution of noise. It is not observable and we have to estimate the parameters. I gave you example of classical regression problem. I transformed your problem to the classical one . What is not clear? my estimation gets PDF of $\epsilon_i$ most similar to $N(0,1)$.

Comment: It's hard to believe thar PDF of $\epsilon_i(\hat \alpha)=(x_i \frac{\sum_i x_i/\delta_i}{\sum_i x_i^2/\delta_i} - 1)/\delta_i$ is most similar to $N(0,1)$. The goal of your solution is to minimize the variance of $\epsilon_i$ rather than to make it equal to 1. Furthermore, you don't take into account the mean of $\epsilon_i(\alpha)$ which should be close to zero.

Comment: Well u don't have to believe - u have to understand. You have an equation $1=x_ia+\delta_i \epsilon_i$ . So you look for $a$ minimizing variance $1-x_ia$.  Take in account weights $1/\delta_i$.1The final solution makes sample $\epsilon_i$ closet to distribution $N(0,1)$ . I strongly suggest you to read classical regression analysis. And yes I edited my solution fixing some typos.

Comment: Why would this estimator be preferable to the unbiased estimator $$\tilde\alpha=\frac{\sum\limits_ix_i/\delta_i}{\sum\limits_i1/\delta_i},$$ which, at least when the number $n$ of sensors is large and their variances are comparable, seems to have a variance of order $1/n$ while $\hat\alpha$ in this answer seems to have a variance of order $1$?

Comment: Of course your estimator makes sense. You even can derive that it minimizes $\sum_i 1/\sqrt(\delta_i) (x_i -\alpha)^2$. The mine however is based on original assumption of distribution of $\zeta_i$. And its variance also converges to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Alexander, what about the reliability of the suggested estimate? Is it unbiased? What is the variance?

Comment: Well this a bgood question. I will write something about this in the answer. I have to think, it is not so obvious.

Comment: Max, I extended my answer. I did not answer your questions yet and made the picture even more complicating. It is not so trivial. I apology for being a bit rude with you.

Comment: Alexander, it's very good extension, thanks. The 3rd estimator is little bit surprising and at first sight it is unbiased. Could you specify the variance for it?

Comment: For the variant 3 it is very simple. Sorry I don't have time to go through 1,2 and it seems for me now that 3 is what you really need. I will add the analysis for 3 into the answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the variance formula. Actually, we don't know the true $\alpha$. Can we substitute $\alpha^*$ by the its estimated value?

Comment: Finally yes, since we see that $\alpha\to \alpha^*$. But originally how I understand now the problem the equation $x_i=\alpha \zeta_i$  means that $x_i$ is a perturbation of the true hidden $\alpha^*$ by random mulitplier $\zeta_i$. I think we don't have right to say we perturb "estimated alpha". We perturb true $\alpha$ and try to estimate it.Please understand that ture $\alpha$ is constant, while the estimated $\alpha$ is a random variable.You cannnot say $var$ is randnom.